# Laptop overheating Problem in Ubuntu 12.04 only

Tags: 12.04, drivers, overheating

I'm having the problem of overheating on my Ubuntu partition.

```
acpitz-virtual-0
Adapter: Virtual device
temp1:        +82.0°C  (crit = +95.0°C)
temp2:        +77.0°C  (crit = +95.0°C)

k10temp-pci-00c3
Adapter: PCI adapter
temp1:        +88.5°C  (high = +70.0°C)
```

Top shows that Chrome and avahi are my only two processes running at the moment, both below 25%.

I'm running Ubuntu 12.04 on a Gateway NV53 with AMD Athlon II X2 MX300 processor.

I've read through other threads related to this problem but cannot figure out the problem. Some have suggested it is the graphics driver, but if I open up "Additional Drivers" then I just get "there are no proprietary drivers are in use on this system".

Can anyone help me sovle the problem of constant overheating?

Answer (score 1):

"no proprietary drivers" means that you are using the open drivers for ubuntu 12.04 on your ATI Mobility Radeon™ HD 4570. That can become rather hot in a thermically-not-very-well-designed laptop.

Install the proprietary drivers through the "extra drivers" or "closed drivers" icon.
it wil let your system run way cooler.

(on my netbook the difference was 20-30 degrees centigrade)

Comment: Oh, and clean out the cooling ducts. After a few years of use it will have gathered enough dust to block the ventilation.

Comment: I cannot find either of those icons. And I my "Software Sources" menu does not have a "additional drivers" tab that I've seen mentioned either.

Comment: in that case, follow paragraph 2 of this guide: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BinaryDriverHowto/ATI